# Compiling 3D asymptote diagrams in a LaTeX document on TeXShop (Mac)

Tags: asymptote, mactex

I am capable of compiling 3D diagrams from the command line with the asy command, but they will not compile within a .tex file. Is there any way to get these 3D diagrams into a pdf relatively easily?

Comment: Run `asy` with the `-k` option to keep the intermediate files. In one of the generated `tex` files, you will find the code that embeds the `prc` file, or use package `media9` for that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Asymptote engine for TeXShop. Us the `TeXShop->Open ~/Library/TeXShop` menu command and then open the Engines folder and then the Inactive and Asymptote folders for instructions on its use.

Alternatively you could use the pdflatexmk engine along with the platexmkrc file found in ~/Library/TeXShop (as before) and then go down to the Engines/Inactive/Latexmk/platexmkrc samples/for Asymptote folder for a copy of the necessary platexmkrc file. Place a copy of that in the folder with your document and add the line `% !TEX program = pdflatexmk` to the top of your file and typeset using the Typeset->Typeset (Cmd-T) menu command; you document will be completely typeset.